# WinDBG Help - Access Violation in Managed Code

Tags: c#, windbg, access-violation

I have a server application written in C#. The application uses no 3rd party software or DLLs, its all managed. Clients connect to the server via socket.

Eventually, the application fails due to an Access Violation exception. Sometimes it will run for minutes, hours, or days without the error occurring. I *believe* the error is occurring when a new client connects but I'm not sure. I've managed to get WinDBG to break when an access violation occurs but I'm not very savy with it.

Heres what I have from WinDBG. I'm just including the output from several commands... Please let me know if there is anything else I should be getting.

```
(dc8.f94): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
ntdll!DbgBreakPoint:
00000000`77ef24f0 cc              int     3
0:090> g
(dc8.bbc): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
(dc8.bbc): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
(dc8.790): Access violation - code c0000005 (first chance)
First chance exceptions are reported before any exception handling.
This exception may be expected and handled.
00000644`802cecd2 8b9f80000000    mov     ebx,dword ptr [rdi+80h] ds:00000000`00000080=????????

0:102> !analyze -v

*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Exception Analysis                                   *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Windows.Forms\b63c84f87c8a3b5d06ed5d24b2213db9\System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll
GetPageUrlData failed, server returned HTTP status 404
URL requested: http://watson.microsoft.com/StageOne/Reborn_WorldServer_exe/1_0_0_0/unknown/0_0_0_0/802cecd2.htm?Retriage=1

FAULTING_IP: 
+84
00000644`802cecd2 8b9f80000000    mov     ebx,dword ptr [rdi+80h]

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffffffffffffffff -- (.exr 0xffffffffffffffff)
ExceptionAddress: 00000644802cecd2
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 0000000000000000
   Parameter[1]: 0000000000000080
Attempt to read from address 0000000000000080

FAULTING_THREAD:  0000000000000790

PROCESS_NAME:  Reborn_WorldServer.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at "0x%08lx" referenced memory at "0x%08lx". The memory could not be "%s".

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at "0x%08lx" referenced memory at "0x%08lx". The memory could not be "%s".

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  0000000000000000

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  0000000000000080

READ_ADDRESS:  0000000000000080 

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
clr!CallDescrWorker+84
00000644`7f1410b4 8b4d38          mov     ecx,dword ptr [rbp+38h]

FAILED_INSTRUCTION_ADDRESS: 
+84
00000644`802cecd2 8b9f80000000    mov     ebx,dword ptr [rdi+80h]

MOD_LIST: 

NTGLOBALFLAG:  70

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0

IP_ON_HEAP:  0000064480173fc8

MANAGED_STACK: 
(TransitionMU)
000000006993C960 00000644802CECD2 Reborn_WorldServer!App1AppHandler.Character.AddMapItems(System.Collections.Generic.List`1, Boolean)+0x152
000000006993CB00 0000064480173FC8 Reborn_WorldServer!App1AppHandler.LootManager.DropItems(Int32, Int32, System.Collections.Generic.List`1, Boolean)+0x9d8
000000006993CDC0 00000644802E803B Reborn_WorldServer!App1AppHandler.Creature.DropLoot(Int32)+0x4cb
000000006993CE90 00000644802E71EC Reborn_WorldServer!App1AppHandler.CreatureBase.InflictDamage(Int32, Int32)+0x47c
000000006993CFC0 00000644802F8807 Reborn_WorldServer!App1AppHandler.CreatureBase.InflictSpellDamage(Int32, Int32, Int64, System.String, Int32 ByRef)+0x177
000000006993D030 00000644802F68DF Reborn_WorldServer!Reborn_Server.App1AppHandler.Spell_Lightening.Cast(App1AppHandler.CreatureBase, Int32, Int64)+0x66f
(TransitionUM)
(TransitionMU)
000000006993DEA0 000006447837587F mscorlib_ni!System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(System.Object, System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder, System.Object[], System.Globalization.CultureInfo, Boolean)+0x27f
000000006993DFE0 00000644783C0426 mscorlib_ni!System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(System.Object, System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder, System.Object[], System.Globalization.CultureInfo)+0x26
000000006993E030 00000644783E1AEE mscorlib_ni!System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(System.String, System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder, System.Object, System.Object[], System.Reflection.ParameterModifier[], System.Globalization.CultureInfo, System.String[])+0xcbe
000000006993E170 00000644802F6155 Reborn_WorldServer!App1AppHandler.AppHandler2.Spell_CastTarget(App1AppHandler.Character, Int64)+0x415
000000006993E2A0 000006448019B452 Reborn_WorldServer!Reborn_WorldServer.Form1.onClientDataRecieved(System.IAsyncResult)+0x2792
000000006993E3F0 0000064475282655 System_ni!System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr)+0xc5
000000006993E450 0000064478383178 mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(System.Object)+0x178
(TransitionUM)
(TransitionMU)
000000006993ECA0 00000644783717E1 mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)+0xa1
000000006993ED00 000006447837172B mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)+0x3b
000000006993ED50 000006447528D23A System_ni!System.Net.ContextAwareResult.Complete(IntPtr)+0xda
000000006993EDB0 000006447528D0D9 System_ni!System.Net.Sockets.BaseOverlappedAsyncResult.CompletionPortCallback(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)+0x139
000000006993EE40 0000064478A988E6 mscorlib_ni!System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)+0x96
(TransitionUM)

MANAGED_STACK_COMMAND:  _EFN_StackTrace

BUGCHECK_STR:  APPLICATION_FAULT_NULL_CLASS_PTR_DEREFERENCE_BAD_INSTRUCTION_PTR_INVALID_POINTER_READ_WRONG_SYMBOLS_CALL

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  NULL_CLASS_PTR_DEREFERENCE_INVALID_POINTER_READ_CALL

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  NULL_CLASS_PTR_DEREFERENCE_INVALID_POINTER_READ_CALL

FRAME_ONE_INVALID: 1

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 0000064480173fc8 to 00000644802cecd2

STACK_TEXT:  
00000000`6993c960 00000644`80173fc8 : 00000000`9edc46d0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000644`801dc410 : 0x644`802cecd2
00000000`6993cb00 00000644`802e803b : 00000000`263ee088 00000644`0000001e 00000000`00000013 00000000`0c52da60 : 0x644`80173fc8
00000000`6993cdc0 00000644`802e71ec : 00000000`26fe5bb8 00000644`00000249 00000000`9edc46d0 00000644`8022b668 : 0x644`802e803b
00000000`6993ce90 00000644`802f8807 : 00000000`26fe5bb8 00000000`0000029a ffffffff`00000249 00000000`0000029a : 0x644`802e71ec
00000000`6993cfc0 00000644`802f68df : 00000000`9f066ff0 00000644`80224880 00000000`025edfc8 00000000`00000005 : 0x644`802f8807
00000000`6993d030 00000644`7f1410b4 : 00000000`9f0a7bf0 00000000`9edc46d0 00000000`0000001a 00000000`000002b1 : 0x644`802f68df
00000000`6993d250 00000644`7f1411c9 : 00000000`6993e170 00000000`00050000 00000000`6993dd70 00000000`00000000 : clr!CallDescrWorker+0x84
00000000`6993d2b0 00000644`7f141245 : 00000000`6993d3c8 00000000`00000004 00000000`6993d3f0 00000000`6993d870 : clr!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+0xa9
00000000`6993d330 00000644`7f307ef9 : 00000000`6993d948 00000000`00000000 00000000`6993d850 00000000`1ce92f20 : clr!MethodDesc::CallDescr+0x2a1
00000000`6993d580 00000644`7f307dbf : 00000000`00000003 00000000`9f0a8148 00000000`00000003 00000000`00000000 : clr!CallWithValueTypes_RetArgSlotWrapper+0x91
00000000`6993d810 00000644`7f307a74 : 00000644`00000000 00000644`7f1b53b9 00000000`9f0a7bf0 00000000`9f0a7bf0 : clr!InvokeImpl+0x2e6
00000000`6993dcb0 00000644`7837587f : 00000000`9f0a85f0 00000000`9f0a7bf0 00000000`9f0a8918 00000000`6993df20 : clr!RuntimeMethodHandle::InvokeMethodFast+0x1d8
00000000`6993dea0 00000644`783c0426 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`9f0a7bc0 00000000`9f0a7bf0 00000000`9f0a8308 : mscorlib_ni+0x37587f
00000000`6993dfe0 00000644`783e1aee : 00000000`9f0a8818 00000000`00000000 00000000`9f0a8308 00000644`802c4646 : mscorlib_ni+0x3c0426
00000000`6993e030 00000644`802f6155 : 00000000`9f0a7bc0 00000000`2906d520 00000644`0000011c 00000000`024f5210 : mscorlib_ni+0x3e1aee
00000000`6993e170 00000644`8019b452 : 00000000`024cdf08 00000000`9edc46d0 00000000`000002b1 00000000`ffffffff : 0x644`802f6155
00000000`6993e2a0 00000644`75282655 : 00000000`024d0f78 00000000`6993e410 00000000`6993e688 00000000`9ebbfe88 : 0x644`8019b452
00000000`6993e3f0 00000644`78383178 : 00000000`9ebbfd40 00000000`6993e488 ffffffff`fffffffe 00000644`7f1410b4 : System_ni+0x242655
00000000`6993e450 00000644`7f1410b4 : 00000000`025063f8 00000000`9f083128 00000000`00000003 00000000`00000003 : mscorlib_ni+0x383178
00000000`6993e510 00000644`7f1411c9 : 00000000`6993e600 00000000`6993e7f8 00000644`7839f5b0 00000000`00000000 : clr!CallDescrWorker+0x84
00000000`6993e560 00000644`7f141245 : 00000000`6993e678 00000000`00000002 00000000`6993e690 00000000`6993e888 : clr!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+0xa9
00000000`6993e5e0 00000644`7f1c717e : 00000000`9ebbfe40 00000000`00000000 00000000`6993eaf8 00000000`6993e930 : clr!MethodDesc::CallDescr+0x2a1
00000000`6993e820 00000644`7f1c6fa5 : 00000000`9ebbfe40 00000644`7f77ffc0 00000000`1ce92f20 00000644`784cc848 : clr!ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanupHelper+0x152
00000000`6993ead0 00000644`783717e1 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`9f0830e8 00000000`124c1030 00000000`00000000 : clr!ReflectionInvocation::ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup+0x1a5
00000000`6993eca0 00000644`7837172b : 00000000`00000000 00000644`783b211e 00000000`00000000 00000644`7f1d5af9 : mscorlib_ni+0x3717e1
00000000`6993ed00 00000644`7528d23a : 00000000`00000000 00000644`75282532 00000644`784cc848 00000644`75785fab : mscorlib_ni+0x37172b
00000000`6993ed50 00000644`7528d0d9 : 00000000`9ebbfd40 00000644`7f1dc72e 00000000`00000000 ffffffff`fffffffe : System_ni+0x24d23a
00000000`6993edb0 00000644`78a988e6 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000024 00000000`6993f0d8 00000000`9f0e58f0 : System_ni+0x24d0d9
00000000`6993ee40 00000644`7f1410b4 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000024 00000000`028ac818 00000000`00000000 : mscorlib_ni+0xa988e6
00000000`6993eea0 00000644`7f1411c9 : 00000000`40000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 : clr!CallDescrWorker+0x84
00000000`6993ef00 00000644`7f1432b4 : 00000000`6993f0c0 00000000`00000003 00000644`78330490 00000000`00000000 : clr!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+0xa9
00000000`6993ef80 00000644`7f143efc : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 000007ff`ffe3c000 00000644`7f2712a8 : clr!DispatchCallDebuggerWrapper+0x74
00000000`6993f020 00000644`7f354683 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`028ac818 00000000`00000024 00000000`00000000 : clr!DispatchCallNoEH+0x7c
00000000`6993f080 00000644`7f1d7096 : 00000000`028ac7c8 00000000`6993f320 00000000`6993f3c0 00000000`6993f320 : clr!BindIoCompletionCallBack_Worker+0xc3
00000000`6993f120 00000644`7f1d702b : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : clr!QueueUserWorkItemManagedCallback+0x92
00000000`6993f160 00000644`7f1d6f98 : ffffffff`fffffffe 0000fa6f`a44b9288 00000000`00000000 00000644`7f1dff70 : clr!EEUtf8HashTableHelper::Hash+0xe8
00000000`6993f260 00000644`7f1d70ef : ffffffff`ffffffff 00000000`1ce92f20 00000000`00000000 00000644`7f357138 : clr!IncCantStopCount+0xbd
00000000`6993f300 00000644`7f35341e : 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000644`7f337610 : clr!COMArrayInfo::GetReference+0x12b
00000000`6993f360 00000644`7f3562a9 : 00000000`1ce92f20 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000001 : clr!BindIoCompletionCallbackStubEx+0xae
00000000`6993f3e0 00000644`7f1cd226 : 00000000`1ce92f20 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 : clr!BindIoCompletionCallbackStub+0x9
00000000`6993f410 00000644`7f3247c6 : 00000000`1bad1320 00000000`00000024 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : clr!ThreadpoolMgr::CompletionPortThreadStart+0x19a
00000000`6993f4c0 00000000`77d6b71a : 00000000`1bb0d050 00000644`7f324750 00000000`00000000 00000000`6993ffa8 : clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+0x7d
00000000`6993ff80 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : KERNEL32!BaseThreadStart+0x3a


SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  6

SYMBOL_NAME:  clr!CallDescrWorker+84

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: clr

IMAGE_NAME:  clr.dll

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  4ba21eeb

STACK_COMMAND:  dt ntdll!LdrpLastDllInitializer BaseDllName ; dt ntdll!LdrpFailureData ; ~102s ; kb

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  NULL_CLASS_PTR_DEREFERENCE_INVALID_POINTER_READ_CALL_c0000005_clr.dll!CallDescrWorker

BUCKET_ID:  X64_APPLICATION_FAULT_NULL_CLASS_PTR_DEREFERENCE_BAD_INSTRUCTION_PTR_INVALID_POINTER_READ_WRONG_SYMBOLS_CALL_BAD_IP_clr!CallDescrWorker+84

WATSON_STAGEONE_URL:  http://watson.microsoft.com/StageOne/Reborn_WorldServer_exe/1_0_0_0/4da5fc4b/unknown/0_0_0_0/bbbbbbb4/c0000005/802cecd2.htm?Retriage=1

Followup: MachineOwner


0:102> !dumpstack

OS Thread Id: 0x790 (102)
Current frame: (MethodDesc 00000644801dc1f0 +0x152 App1AppHandler.Character.AddMapItems(System.Collections.Generic.List`1, Boolean))
Child-SP         RetAddr          Caller, Callee
000000006993caa0 00000644802f8da5 (MethodDesc 00000644801dc1e0 +0x65 App1AppHandler.Character.AddMapItem(App1AppHandler.MapItem)), calling clr!JIT_Stelem_Ref
000000006993caf0 0000064480173fc8 (MethodDesc 0000064480220170 +0x9d8 App1AppHandler.LootManager.DropItems(Int32, Int32, System.Collections.Generic.List`1, Boolean)), calling (MethodDesc 00000644801dc1e0 +0 App1AppHandler.Character.AddMapItem(App1AppHandler.MapItem))
000000006993cb70 000006447f14f236 clr!JIT_SetFieldObj+0x2f6, calling clr!GetThread
000000006993cd50 0000064480178694 (MethodDesc 00000644801d57b8 +0x54 App1AppHandler.CreatureBase.get_MapY()), calling 000006447f1031d0 (stub for System.Threading.Monitor.Exit(System.Object))
000000006993cdb0 00000644802e803b (MethodDesc 00000644801d5d50 +0x4cb App1AppHandler.Creature.DropLoot(Int32)), calling (MethodDesc 0000064480220170 +0 App1AppHandler.LootManager.DropItems(Int32, Int32, System.Collections.Generic.List`1, Boolean))
000000006993cde0 0000064480170e01 (MethodDesc 0000064480223910 +0x161 Reborn_Server.App1AppHandler.BuffManager.GetBuffByStackType(System.String)), calling 000006447f1031d0 (stub for System.Threading.Monitor.Exit(System.Object))
000000006993ce80 00000644802e71ec (MethodDesc 00000644801d5690 +0x47c App1AppHandler.CreatureBase.InflictDamage(Int32, Int32))
000000006993cfb0 00000644802f8807 (MethodDesc 00000644801d5698 +0x177 App1AppHandler.CreatureBase.InflictSpellDamage(Int32, Int32, Int64, System.String, Int32 ByRef))
000000006993cfe0 00000644802f85a6 (MethodDesc 00000644801d56b0 +0x16 App1AppHandler.CreatureBase.CalculateGetSpellDamagePerResists(Int32, System.String)), calling (MethodDesc 00000644801d5708 +0 App1AppHandler.CreatureBase.getResist(System.String))
000000006993d020 00000644802f68df (MethodDesc 00000644802bdbd0 +0x66f Reborn_Server.App1AppHandler.Spell_Lightening.Cast(App1AppHandler.CreatureBase, Int32, Int64))
000000006993d240 000006447f1410b4 clr!CallDescrWorker+0x84
000000006993d270 0000000077edb9e9 ntdll!RtlFreeHeap+0x15e, calling ntdll!RtlFreeHeapSlowly
000000006993d2a0 000006447f1411c9 clr!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+0xa9, calling clr!CallDescrWorker
000000006993d320 000006447f141245 clr!MethodDesc::CallDescr+0x2a1, calling clr!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler
000000006993d380 000006447f149cdb clr!MetaSig::MetaSig+0x4b, calling MSVCR100_CLR0400!memmove
000000006993d390 000006447f111356 clr!MethodDesc::TryGetMultiCallableAddrOfCode+0x2be, calling clr!MethodDesc::GetTemporaryEntryPoint
000000006993d3b0 000006447f149de6 clr!MethodDesc::CallDescr+0xed, calling clr!_chkstk
000000006993d570 000006447f307ef9 clr!CallWithValueTypes_RetArgSlotWrapper+0x91, calling clr!MethodDesc::CallDescr
000000006993d5b0 000006447f14f236 clr!JIT_SetFieldObj+0x2f6, calling clr!GetThread
000000006993d6d0 000006447f149cdb clr!MetaSig::MetaSig+0x4b, calling MSVCR100_CLR0400!memmove
000000006993d800 000006447f307dbf clr!InvokeImpl+0x2e6, calling clr!CallWithValueTypes_RetArgSlotWrapper
000000006993d9d0 000006447f1040e9 clr!CLRException::HandlerState::HandlerState+0xe, calling clr!GetThread
000000006993d9e0 000006447f14c2ba clr!MetaSig::MetaSig+0x7b, calling clr!memcpy
000000006993dca0 000006447f307a74 clr!RuntimeMethodHandle::InvokeMethodFast+0x1d8, calling clr!InvokeImpl
000000006993dcb0 000006447f1b53b9 clr!ReflectionInvocation::PerformSecurityCheck+0x69
000000006993dd40 000006447f14a2e3 clr!GCInterface::KeepAlive+0x23, calling clr!GetThread
000000006993ddb8 000006447837587f (MethodDesc 000006447807d7f8 +0x27f System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(System.Object, System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder, System.Object[], System.Globalization.CultureInfo, Boolean)), calling 000006447f30789c (stub for System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(System.IRuntimeMethodInfo, System.Object, System.Object[], System.SignatureStruct ByRef, System.Reflection.MethodAttributes, System.RuntimeType))
000000006993de50 000006447f307960 clr!RuntimeMethodHandle::InvokeMethodFast+0xc4, calling clr!LazyMachStateCaptureState
000000006993de60 000006447f102179 clr!JIT_MemCpy+0x9, calling clr!JIT_memmove
000000006993de90 000006447837587f (MethodDesc 000006447807d7f8 +0x27f System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(System.Object, System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder, System.Object[], System.Globalization.CultureInfo, Boolean)), calling 000006447f30789c (stub for System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(System.IRuntimeMethodInfo, System.Object, System.Object[], System.SignatureStruct ByRef, System.Reflection.MethodAttributes, System.RuntimeType))
000000006993dfd0 00000644783c0426 (MethodDesc 000006447807d7f0 +0x26 System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(System.Object, System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder, System.Object[], System.Globalization.CultureInfo)), calling (MethodDesc 000006447807d7f8 +0 System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(System.Object, System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder, System.Object[], System.Globalization.CultureInfo, Boolean))
000000006993e020 00000644783e1aee (MethodDesc 000006447807b0f8 +0xcbe System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(System.String, System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder, System.Object, System.Object[], System.Reflection.ParameterModifier[], System.Globalization.CultureInfo, System.String[]))
000000006993e040 00000644802c4646 (MethodDesc 000006448022b4a0 +0x296 Reborn_Server.App1AppHandler.SkillManager.GetCurrentLevel(System.String)), calling (MethodDesc 0000064478186140 +0 System.Decimal.Round(System.Decimal, Int32))
000000006993e0a0 000007ff7ec7c2d5 OLEAUT32!VarDecInt+0x14, calling OLEAUT32!DecFixInt
000000006993e110 000006447f758abc clr!COMDecimal::ToInt32+0xdc, calling clr!_security_check_cookie
000000006993e160 00000644802f6155 (MethodDesc 00000644801d0438 +0x415 App1AppHandler.AppHandler2.Spell_CastTarget(App1AppHandler.Character, Int64))
000000006993e290 000006448019b452 (MethodDesc 0000064480048220 +0x2792 Reborn_WorldServer.Form1.onClientDataRecieved(System.IAsyncResult)), calling 000006448004c3d0 (stub for App1AppHandler.AppHandler2.Spell_CastTarget(App1AppHandler.Character, Int64))
000000006993e2e0 0000064478383502 (MethodDesc 0000064478090ab0 +0x372 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.SetExecutionContext(System.Threading.ExecutionContext)), calling clr!JIT_CheckedWriteBarrier
000000006993e2f0 000006447838c658 (MethodDesc 00000644780070e0 +0x48 System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].RemoveAt(Int32)), calling clr!JIT_Stelem_Ref
000000006993e390 000006447f111279 clr!MethodDesc::TryGetMultiCallableAddrOfCode+0x15e, calling clr!MethodDesc::GetNativeCode
000000006993e3e0 0000064475282655 (MethodDesc 000006447510a218 +0xc5 System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr))
000000006993e440 0000064478383178 (MethodDesc 0000064478090a90 +0x178 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(System.Object))
000000006993e460 000006447f1410b4 clr!CallDescrWorker+0x84
000000006993e500 000006447f1410b4 clr!CallDescrWorker+0x84
000000006993e550 000006447f1411c9 clr!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+0xa9, calling clr!CallDescrWorker
000000006993e5d0 000006447f141245 clr!MethodDesc::CallDescr+0x2a1, calling clr!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler
000000006993e620 000006447f149cdb clr!MetaSig::MetaSig+0x4b, calling MSVCR100_CLR0400!memmove
000000006993e640 000006447f273451 clr!Holder,2>::~Holder,2>+0x21, calling clr!FunctionBase::DoRelease
000000006993e650 000006447f149de6 clr!MethodDesc::CallDescr+0xed, calling clr!_chkstk
000000006993e730 000006447f273471 clr!Thread::EndPrepareCerForHolder+0xe, calling clr!GetThread
000000006993e750 000006447f154582 clr!MethodCallGraphPreparer::Run+0x10e, calling clr!_security_check_cookie
000000006993e760 000006447f273451 clr!Holder,2>::~Holder,2>+0x21, calling clr!FunctionBase::DoRelease
000000006993e810 000006447f1c717e clr!ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanupHelper+0x152, calling clr!MethodDesc::CallDescr
000000006993e960 000006447f273471 clr!Thread::EndPrepareCerForHolder+0xe, calling clr!GetThread
000000006993e980 000006447f154582 clr!MethodCallGraphPreparer::Run+0x10e, calling clr!_security_check_cookie
000000006993e990 000006447f273451 clr!Holder,2>::~Holder,2>+0x21, calling clr!FunctionBase::DoRelease
000000006993ea90 000006447f14a040 clr!MethodDescCallSite::DefaultInit+0x48, calling clr!MetaSig::ForceSigWalk
000000006993eac0 000006447f1c6fa5 clr!ReflectionInvocation::ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup+0x1a5, calling clr!ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanupHelper
000000006993eb60 000006447f1d5d1c clr!JIT_Box+0x27c, calling clr!HelperMethodFrameRestoreState
000000006993ebd8 00000644783717e1 (MethodDesc 0000064478090a70 +0xa1 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)), calling (MethodDesc 0000064478090a80 +0 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object))
000000006993ec70 000006447f1c6e50 clr!ReflectionInvocation::ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup+0x50, calling clr!LazyMachStateCaptureState
000000006993ec90 00000644783717e1 (MethodDesc 0000064478090a70 +0xa1 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)), calling (MethodDesc 0000064478090a80 +0 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object))
000000006993ecf0 000006447837172b (MethodDesc 0000064478090a60 +0x3b System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)), calling (MethodDesc 0000064478090a70 +0 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean))
000000006993ed00 00000644783b211e (MethodDesc 000006447807c950 +0x1e System.MulticastDelegate.CtorClosed(System.Object, IntPtr)), calling clr!JIT_WriteBarrier_Fast
000000006993ed10 000006447f1d5af9 clr!JIT_Box+0x59, calling clr!LazyMachStateCaptureState
000000006993ed20 000006447f1d5fcb clr!Thread::EnterRuntimeNoThrow+0x27, calling ntdll!RtlSetLastWin32Error
000000006993ed40 000006447528d23a (MethodDesc 00000644750abb20 +0xda System.Net.ContextAwareResult.Complete(IntPtr)), calling (MethodDesc 0000064478090a60 +0 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object))
000000006993ed50 0000064475282532 (MethodDesc 000006447510a318 +0x82 System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(System.Object, IntPtr)), calling clr!JIT_WriteBarrier_Fast
000000006993ed60 0000064475785fab (MethodDesc 000006447510a328 +0x1b System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.InvokeCallback(System.Object)), calling clr!JIT_GetSharedNonGCStaticBaseNoCtor_InlineGetAppDomain
000000006993eda0 000006447528d0d9 (MethodDesc 0000064475109700 +0x139 System.Net.Sockets.BaseOverlappedAsyncResult.CompletionPortCallback(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)), calling (MethodDesc 000006447510a328 +0 System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.InvokeCallback(System.Object))
000000006993edb0 000006447f1dc72e clr!ThreadpoolMgr::ShouldGrowCompletionPortThreadpool+0x1a, calling clr!Volatile::operator==
000000006993ede0 000006447f356100 clr!CheckVMForIOPacket+0x68, calling clr!ThreadpoolMgr::CompletionPortDispatchWorkWithinAppDomain
000000006993ee30 0000064478a988e6 (MethodDesc 00000644781b06f0 +0x96 System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*))
000000006993ee90 000006447f1410b4 clr!CallDescrWorker+0x84
000000006993eef0 000006447f1411c9 clr!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+0xa9, calling clr!CallDescrWorker
000000006993ef70 000006447f1432b4 clr!DispatchCallDebuggerWrapper+0x74, calling clr!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler
000000006993f010 000006447f143efc clr!DispatchCallNoEH+0x7c, calling clr!DispatchCallDebuggerWrapper
000000006993f030 000006447f2712a8 clr!ThreadStore::CheckForEEShutdown+0x1e, calling clr!ThreadStore::OtherThreadsComplete
000000006993f070 000006447f354683 clr!BindIoCompletionCallBack_Worker+0xc3, calling clr!DispatchCallNoEH
000000006993f110 000006447f1d7096 clr!QueueUserWorkItemManagedCallback+0x92
000000006993f150 000006447f1d702b clr!EEUtf8HashTableHelper::Hash+0xe8, calling clr!QueueUserWorkItemManagedCallback+0x60
000000006993f180 0000000077f61728 ntdll!RtlDebugAllocateHeap+0x108, calling ntdll!RtlpGetExtraStuffPointer
000000006993f190 0000000077d704ff KERNEL32!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x130, calling ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject
000000006993f210 000006447f1d5fcb clr!Thread::EnterRuntimeNoThrow+0x27, calling ntdll!RtlSetLastWin32Error
000000006993f230 000006447f1e0000 clr!CLREvent::WaitEx+0x1a9, calling ntdll!RtlSetLastWin32Error
000000006993f250 000006447f1d6f98 clr!IncCantStopCount+0xbd, calling clr!EEUtf8HashTableHelper::Hash+0x70
000000006993f270 000006447f1dff70 clr!CLREvent::WaitEx+0xf8, calling clr!CLREvent::WaitEx+0x128
000000006993f2d0 000006447f1dfe23 clr!CLREvent::WaitEx+0x5e, calling clr!CLREvent::WaitEx+0xd8
000000006993f2f0 000006447f1d70ef clr!COMArrayInfo::GetReference+0x12b, calling clr!IncCantStopCount+0x20
000000006993f310 000006447f357138 clr!Holder,&ResetThreadSecurityState,0,&CompareDefault,2>::~Holder,&ResetThreadSecurityState,0,&CompareDefault,2>+0x24, calling clr!ResetThreadSecurityState
000000006993f350 000006447f35341e clr!BindIoCompletionCallbackStubEx+0xae, calling clr!COMArrayInfo::GetReference+0xfc
000000006993f370 000006447f337610 clr!WKS::gc_heap::wait_for_gc_done+0x60, calling clr!CLREvent::Wait
000000006993f3d0 000006447f3562a9 clr!BindIoCompletionCallbackStub+0x9, calling clr!BindIoCompletionCallbackStubEx
000000006993f400 000006447f1cd226 clr!ThreadpoolMgr::CompletionPortThreadStart+0x19a
000000006993f470 000006447f106a19 clr!operator delete+0x3a, calling clr!ClrFreeInProcessHeap
000000006993f4b0 000006447f3247c6 clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+0x7d
000000006993f510 0000000077edc3d6 ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap+0x1292, calling ntdll!RtlAllocateHeapSlowly
000000006993f570 0000000077edc3d6 ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap+0x1292, calling ntdll!RtlAllocateHeapSlowly
000000006993f5f0 0000000077edc3d6 ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap+0x1292, calling ntdll!RtlAllocateHeapSlowly
000000006993f6f0 000007ff7ebc1fb3 OLEAUT32!DllMain+0x1f3, calling OLEAUT32!_security_check_cookie
000000006993f760 00000644ff541dfa mscoreei!calloc_impl+0x5d, calling ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap
000000006993f7b0 000007ff7d371ea8 CRYPT32!CertStoreDllMain+0x18, calling CRYPT32!I_RegStoreDllMain
000000006993f7c0 000007ff7d3720f5 CRYPT32!CryptPFXDllMain+0x31, calling CRYPT32!EncodeDecodeDllMain
000000006993f7f0 000007ff7d371bf5 CRYPT32!DllMain+0x1b2, calling CRYPT32
```

Comment: You caught a NullReferenceException in a socket completion callback.  Not locking shared state properly is the typical guess.

Comment: Heh, sorry its all just output from WinDBG. I only included the "!analyze -v", and "!dumpstack" commands because there was no more room.

Comment: Do you think dumping the entire encyclopedia Britannica in a question would help or hinder getting an answer?

Comment: This is a first chance AV, which happen occasionally in CRL under normal conditions. When running managed code under WinDbg disable break on first chance AV using 'sxd av' command.